# How to connect Quorum nodes with Remix?

Tags: web3js, remix, quorum

I'm trying to use the Quorum-examples/7nodes to test my contract.
I followed the step on github and open a terminal to attach to node1.
https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-examples/tree/master/examples/7nodes

However, when I used Remix and choose Web3 Provider and enter http://localhost:22000 , but it doesn't work.

I do the same test on Web3.py and it can successfully connect.

Comment: Did you open remix with https:// or http:// ?

Comment: I test them both

Answer (score 1):

Edit the raft-start.sh file and add  **--rpccorsdomain "*"** in the PRIVATE_CONFIG for the nodes that you want to access from Remix.

Comment: I added this option to docker-compose file and it worked just fine.